# How do I set "StyleBoxEmpty" on buttons in Godot?

Tags: godot, gdscript

I'm trying to remove the blue box that appears around focused buttons in Godot. I saw [here](https://godotengine.org/qa/13550/how-to-disable-button-highlighting) that it can be done with "StyleBoxEmpty", but the example picture is a broken link. I have looked through all the node properties, but I cannot find it. Can someone clarify how to enable this property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out...

To remove the unwanted blue "style box" border around focused buttons, do the following:

1. In the inspector for the button node, scroll down until you find "Custom Styles", expand.
2. Under the focus property, set the null value to StyleBoxEmpty.
3. Done.

Answer (score 0):

#### update for Godot 4

"custom styles" is now "Styles" under "Theme Overrides" in the "Control" class

(I had a hard time finding it)

[image]